# Can't restart/connect to ADB in Android Studio: 'the procedure entry point _create_locale could not be located'

Tags: android, adb, entry-point

I can't seem to get ADB started anymore in Android Studio.

I get an error "Error initializing ADB: unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output:"

When i go to the platform-tools folder to restart adb via the command line I get an error: 
**"Entry Point Not Found"**

**'the procedure entro point _create_locale could not be located in the dynamic link library'**

So far I haven't been able to fix this. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue and in my case the issue was with the latest platform tools 28.0.2. So I downgraded my platform tools from 28.0.2 to 28.0.1 and it worked.

You can download the previous platform tools (28.0.1) from below link

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-windows.zip